# Copy paste row without formula references incrementing

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a macro with VBA that finds a specified string, and inserts a new row below each row containing such string. It works (mostly), but every time the formulae are copied in the new row, the references (to another worksheet) are incremented by 1. Unfortunately, due to the nature of the worksheet I cannot use static references with $.

So my question is: how can I, using VBA, prevent autoincrement of formulae references when pasting a previously existing row?

Thank you in advance :)

```
If InStr(1, xRng.Cells(i, 1).Value, previousName) > 0 Then
        Rows(xRng.Cells(i, 1).Row).Copy
        Rows(xRng.Cells(i, 1).Row + 1).Insert CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromRightOrBelow 
        xRng.Cells(i + 1, 1).Value = name
        Worksheets(inWorksheet).Range("B1").Value = name
        Rows(xRng.Cells(i + 1, 1).Row).Replace What:=oldWorksheet, Replacement:=inWorksheet
End If
```

Comment: Think you'd have to amend the formula string after inserting the row.

Comment: I would, but there are 50+ rows with about 40 formulas in each row unfortunately

Comment: If you are inserting rows your formula references will change so you have no choice but to change the formulas in some way. What sort of formulae are we talking about?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using Copy, you could `Insert` a new Row, then change the `.Formula`/`.Value` of each cell in turn manually:

```
Function DuplicateRow(TargetRow AS Long, Optional ws AS Worksheet) AS Boolean
    If ws Is Nothing Then Set ws = ActiveSheet

    DuplicateRow = False    
    If TargetRow >= ws.Rows.Count Then Exit Function

    ws.Rows(TargetRow+1).Insert

    Dim CurrentCell AS Range

    For Each CurrentCell In Intersect(ws.Rows(TargetRow),ws.UsedRange.EntireColumn)
        If CurrentCell.HasFormula Then
            CurrentCell.Offset(1,0).Formula = CurrentCell.Formula
        ElseIf Len(CurrentCell.Value) > 0 Then
            CurrentCell.Offset(1,0).Value = CurrentCell.Value
        End If
    Next CurrentCell

    DuplicateRow = True
End Function
```

This would then make your code

```
If InStr(1, xRng.Cells(i, 1).Value, previousName) > 0 Then
    DuplicateRow xRng.Cells(i, 1).Row, xRng.Worksheet
    xRng.Cells(i + 1, 1).Value = name
    Worksheets(inWorksheet).Range("B1").Value = name
    Rows(xRng.Cells(i + 1, 1).Row).Replace What:=oldWorksheet, Replacement:=inWorksheet
End If
```

Depending on how many columns you have, this may be slower than your existing Copy/Paste

Comment: Neat approach .

Comment: Thank you so much @Chronocidal , your fix works perfectly!